# How to exit program with QCloseEvent?

Tags: c++, qt

I have overridden the closeEvent function in the login dialog's .h file so that it exits the program when emitted:

```
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event){exit(0)}
```

However, it seems to exit the program for whatever button in the dialog I click.
How can I exit only when clicking the 'x' button in the upper-right corner?

Comment: Is the login window your only window? Then QApplication's quitOnLastWindowClosed should do the job. But that's true by default, so you seem to have another setup?

Comment: You should called `close()` for main window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

closeEvent() is called when the dialog wants to close. Obviously, if you click on a dialog's "OK" or "Cancel" button, then it wants to close. This is normal.

Also, the event passed to closeEvent() should be either accepted or ignored. You shouldn't just exit() the application. For example:

```
void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    if (The dialog should close)
        event->accept();
    else
        event->ignore(); // Don't close.
}
```

It doesn't matter why the window wants to close. Whether the user clicked "OK", or "Cancel", or the "X" button in the window frame. You cannot tell. A close event is just that; the window wants to close.

If the dialog is the last window that's open, then QApplication::exec() will return and your program will shut down normally.